# I am getting a class loading error in apache karaf, while some java resources are loaded, what does this correspond to?

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, apache-karaf

We recently switched from OSGI equinox to apache karaf, Seems that the switch to Karaf started causing issues in one of our custom adapter projects.

When being sent messages, our adapter responds with a 500 error 
„            while trying to invoke the method java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(java.lang.String) of a null object returned from javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.getClassClassLoader(java.lang.Class)
„

I am not able to understand the meaning of this error, does this mean the jacax.xml code is not able to locate the class loader? Or is there something else that may be causing this, and how do I identify if the class-loader itself is missing.

Comment: Can you provide some code of your bundle?

Comment: It could be that you have to set the ContextClassLoader to the bundle's classloader before your calls to the xml library, and set it back to what it was afterwards. I'm just guessing here, as I haven't seen your code, but this sounds familiar to issues I've had earlier where a library used ´Class.forName´ to look up a class object.